# Upload iPhone app to other countries' stores?

Tags: iphone, localization, app-store-connect, submission

I made an app and uploaded it through iTunes Connect, and got accepted and all.. but.

The problem is that I now want the app to be available to other countries, since I initially chose to upload it to only a handful of countries..

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just log into iTunesConnect and add whichever stores you like to your app.

Comment: I thought, wth, let me just press all the links I see ... And I finally found it!! Under "Rights and Pricing" >.> ... How is that related, i have no idea....

Comment: Choose Manage Your Apps, select an app, then click Rights and Pricing. If necessary, click the link to "specific stores" to get a list of all the stores.

Comment: can we do this while my app is waiting for review? please respond quick.